# Login with google plus in android app

Tags: android, google-plus

I have a big problem with google plus api.

I would like login in app with google+ account.

I get this:

```
04-10 11:46:01.391: W/GLSUser(7376): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
04-10 11:46:02.262: W/GLSActivity(7376): [apc] Status from wire: INVALID_CLIENT_ID status: null
04-10 11:46:02.262: W/GLSActivity(7376): [apc] Status from wire: INVALID_CLIENT_ID status: null
04-10 11:46:02.262: I/GLSUser(7376): GLS error: INVALID_CLIENT_ID sample@email.com oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
04-10 11:46:02.262: W/GLSActivity(7376): [apc] Status from wire: Unknown status: UNKNOWN
04-10 11:46:02.412: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29047): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

(i was created Client ID for Android application)

Comment: i found solution, turn on Google+ Domains API :)

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/22/android-login-using-google/